# Remove a String from a file which starts from a & and then has 23 characters in it

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I am working on a small program to achieve something.

So I have acheived a file by using the program, but it has a string starts with a '&' in a lot of places.

I will explain the smallest part of my problem.
I have a string, in that string i want to remove some characters, which starts with a '&' followed by 23 digits.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you managed to read the file? What language are you using? Please be more specific. Edit: saw now that post was tagged c++, stupid phone not showing tags.. Byt the rest still applies..

Comment: I can read the file from any editor, in any laguage.
Actually language is not a barrier right now, time is.

Comment: I have tried searching on google, I just thought to ask those cool intelligent guys out there , else I thought to go for string processing, which I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use string.find and string.replace.

The code example here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ shows a perfect way to do it :)

```
std::string content = "some long string";
std::string string_to_replace = "some ";

str.replace(content.find(string_to_replace),string_to_replace.length(),"");
```

This will find string_to_replace in content and replace it with nothing "".  This is assuming you're fixing the problem before writing to file of course.  In this example, it will yield "long string".

Comment: Code examples on that website are generally poor. Please don't reference it!

Comment: Sometimes, but there's nothing wrong with the one in that link - unless you see something I don't :)  I definitely wouldn't recommend learning C++ from it in general though of course, haha.

Comment: Well the `using namespace std` is making me cringe for a start!

Comment: Haha, I'm the opposite - I hate using declarations because people don't learn where the things reside.  I've seen tons of people freak out because they couldn't figure out that stringstream is in std:: and they forgot the using declaration :)  If you always use one you never forget.  It's all a preference thing though!

Comment: If you never use one then you learn about namespaces and where things _actually_ are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to create a loop in order to read all strings in the file:

```
std::ifstream fin( "input.txt" );
std::string line;

std::getline( fin, line );
while( !fin.eof() ) {
    getline( fin, line );
}
```

Of course, you can't modify the file in-place. You need to write the contents of the input file in another file.

```
std::ifstream fin( "input.txt" );
std::ofstream fout( "output.txt" );
std::string line;

std::getline( fin, line );
while( !fin.eof() ) {
    fout << line << std::endl;
    getline( fin, line );
}
```

The only remaining thing is to locate those strings with '&' and eliminate the subsequent 23 characters.

```
std::ifstream fin( "input.txt" );
std::ofstream fout( "output.txt" );
std::string line;

std::getline( fin, line );
while( !fin.eof() ) {
    unsigned int pos = line.find( '&' );

    if ( pos != string::npos ) {
        string line2 = line.substring( 0, pos -1 );
        line2 += line.substring( pos + 23 );
        line = line2;
    }

    fout << line << std::endl;
    std::getline( fin, line );
}
```

Finally, you need to get rid of `input.txt`. Hope this helps.